# Clone SVN via PHP WebSVN over HTTP://

Tags: svn, repository, clone, mirror, websvn

How may I clone/mirror a SVN repository that has no svn:// access but does have a private(forum-login) WebSVN viewer?

Comment: Ouch! Can't you simply request access to the repository?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're talking about WebSVN from http://www.websvn.info/, not just the standard web access to your repository you get just by running an SVN server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was back when I wanted to clone The Forgotten Server private repo on otland.net

This is no longer possible because the repo no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

svn:// access, http:// access - its all the same, one gets passed through svnserve the other gets apssed through apache and mod_svn.

So to clone, you can use svnhotcopy, or svnsync. I like svnsync best as it will incrementally pull down changes - there's plenty of answers on SO describing how to set it up.

Soon there will be a svnadmin rdump which will remotely dump a repository but that'd not quite released yet. You could get it from the very latest svn repository and try it if you wanted to experiment.